# Setting background to a dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I have a dialog that comes up in my app and I wanted to stray away from using the default dialog, to give something slightly more customized. In my dialog layout, I included the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/My_Custom_Background">
```

This does basically what I want it to, it changes the background as expected. However, this only applies to the layout of the contents of the dialog box: the dialog also has a title and the title part of the dialog box is still the default Android theme, then everything under it is customized as I wanted. Is there away to extend the custom background to the entire dialog box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the title bar

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
```

Make sure to call `requestWindowFeature()` before the `setContentView()` otherwise you get a `FATAL EXCEPTION`

Answer (score 2):

you can create your dialog as below

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_custom_dialog_layout);
    mDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mDialog.show();
```

and inside your custom layout, you can set the custom drawable as a background.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate is to remove your dialog titlebar using this...

```
yourdialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and design whole dialog with title inside your layout...